# CursorAdapter with different layout(ImageView,TextView)

Tags: android, layout, xmpp, smack, android-cursoradapter

I am currently working on a chat application that uses Smack and XMPP Server.
I'm storing all the messages in the database and load in the fragment with the help of cursor adapter in the ListView.

Below code doesn't show messages in the ListView and crash when cursor loader is called. 
Thanks in advance

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int mChatType;
private ReceiveMediaMessage receiveMediaMessage;
private ArrayList mArrayList;
private File pathDirectory;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomMessageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int chatType) {
    super(context, c);
    mChatType = chatType;
    mAutoRequery = true;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    if (view != null) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int jidCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbHelper.USERS_JID);
        int nicknameColId = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbHelper.USERS_NAME);
        String jid = cursor.getString(jidCol);
        String nickname = cursor.getString(nicknameColId);
        MessageContainer messageContainer = MessageContainer.fromCursor(cursor);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("[dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss]");
        String createdAtDate = df.format(messageContainer.getCreated());

        Log.v(Constants.LOG, messageContainer.getUserId());
        if (messageContainer.getBody() != null) {
            if (messageContainer.getIncoming() == 0) {
                //myMessages
                holder.chatContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.IMAGE_MESSAGE)) {
                    holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    receiveImage(messageContainer.getBody(), holder);
                } else if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.VIDEO_MESSAGE)) {

                } else if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.AUDIO_MESSAGE)) {

                } else if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.DOCS_MESSAGE)) {

                } else{
                    holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    holder.messageText.setText(messageContainer.getBody());
                }

            } else {
                // other's messages

                holder.chatContainer.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.IMAGE_MESSAGE)) {
                    holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                    receiveImage(messageContainer.getBody(), holder);
                } else if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.VIDEO_MESSAGE)) {

                } else if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.AUDIO_MESSAGE)) {

                } else if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.DOCS_MESSAGE)) {

                } else {
                    holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                    holder.messageText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text_material_light));
                    holder.messageText.setText(messageContainer.getBody());
                }
            }
        }
        if (mChatType == ChatConstants.MULTICHAT_CHAT_STATE) {
            //holder.from.setText(nickname);
        } else {
            //holder.from.setText(jid);
        }


        //holder.messageDate.setText(createdAtDate);
    }
}

private void receiveImage(String body, final ViewHolder holder) {
    mArrayList = new ArrayList();
    String fid = splitFid(body);

    receiveMediaMessage = new ReceiveMediaMessage(mContext, new ReceiveMediaMessage.ReceiveMediaMessageCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEnd(ArrayList response) {
            mArrayList = response;
            pathDirectory = new File(Constants.IMAGE_THUMB_PATH + "IMAGE_" + mArrayList.get(Constants.FID_INDEX).toString() + ".jpg");
            if (pathDirectory.exists()) {
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }
    });
    receiveMediaMessage.execute(fid);

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    MessageContainer messageContainer = MessageContainer.fromCursor(cursor);
    if (messageContainer.getBody().contains(ChatConstants.EDUCHAT_IMAGE_MESSAGE)) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_image_view_row_layout, parent, false);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chat_image_view_row);
        holder.chatContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chat_image_view_container);

    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_text_view_layout, parent, false);
        holder.messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chat_text_view_row);
        holder.chatContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chat_text_view_container);
    }
    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;

}

private static class ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout chatContainer;
    TextView messageText;
    ImageView imageView;
}


private String splitFid(String data) {
    String delimiter = "_";
    String[] temp = data.split(delimiter);
    return temp[2];
}
```

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}
```

Error

```
02-10 00:14:19.125 25518-25518/in.tekticks.educhat E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
02-10 00:14:19.126 25518-25518/in.tekticks.educhat E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-10 00:14:19.127 25518-25518/in.tekticks.educhat E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at in.tekticks.educhat.adapters.CustomMessageCursorAdapter.bindView(CustomMessageCursorAdapter.java:73)
    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4968)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onGenericMotionEvent(AbsListView.java:4008)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEventInternal(View.java:8493)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8474)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2322)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1702)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2775)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:70)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8580)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliver
 02-10 00:14:19.130 25518-25518/in.tekticks.educhat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.tekticks.educhat, PID: 25518
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
  at in.tekticks.educhat.adapters.CustomMessageCursorAdapter.bindView(CustomMessageCursorAdapter.java:73)
  at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4968)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.onGenericMotionEvent(AbsListView.java:4008)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEventInternal(View.java:8493)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8474)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2024)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1975)
  at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:8467)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2322)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1702)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2775)
  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:70)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8580)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(
```

Comment: Always post the full error log stack trace if you say there is crash.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int mChatType;
private File pathDirectory;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomMessageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int chatType) {
    super(context, c);
    mChatType = chatType;
    mAutoRequery = true;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    int jidCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbHelper.USERS_JID);
    int nicknameColId = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbHelper.USERS_NAME);
    String jid = cursor.getString(jidCol);
    String nickname = cursor.getString(nicknameColId);
    MessageContainer messageContainer = MessageContainer.fromCursor(cursor);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("[dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss]");
    String createdAtDate = df.format(messageContainer.getCreated());

    int viewType = this.getItemViewType(cursor);
    if (view != null) {
        if (messageContainer.getBody() != null) {
            if (viewType == 0) {
                if (messageContainer.getIncoming() == 0) {
                    holder.chatContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    String fid =splitFid(messageContainer.getBody());
                    pathDirectory = new File(Constants.IMAGE_SEND_PATH + "IMAGE_" + fid + ".jpg");
                    Log.v(Constants.LOG, "File path:"+pathDirectory.getAbsolutePath().toString());

                    if (pathDirectory.exists()) {
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    }
                } else {
                    holder.chatContainer.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                    String fid =splitFid(messageContainer.getBody());
                    pathDirectory = new File(Constants.IMAGE_THUMB_PATH + "IMAGE_" + fid + ".jpg");
                    if (pathDirectory.exists()) {
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (messageContainer.getIncoming() == 0) {
                    holder.chatContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    holder.messageText.setText(messageContainer.getBody());
                } else {
                    holder.chatContainer.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                    holder.messageText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text_material_light));
                    holder.messageText.setText(messageContainer.getBody());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (mChatType == ChatConstants.MULTICHAT_CHAT_STATE) {
        //holder.from.setText(nickname);
    } else {
        //holder.from.setText(jid);
    }


    //holder.messageDate.setText(createdAtDate);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    int viewType = this.getItemViewType(cursor);
    MessageContainer messageContainer = MessageContainer.fromCursor(cursor);
    if (viewType == 0) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_image_view_row_layout, parent, false);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chat_image_view_row);
        holder.chatContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chat_image_view_container);

    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_text_view_layout, parent, false);
        holder.messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chat_text_view_row);
        holder.chatContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_chat_text_view_container);
    }
    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
    return getItemViewType(cursor);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}

private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
    String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MESSAGES_BODY));
    if (type.contains(ChatConstants.EDUCHAT_IMAGE_MESSAGE)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout chatContainer;
    TextView messageText;
    ImageView imageView;
}
private String splitFid(String data) {
    String delimiter = "_";
    String[] temp = data.split(delimiter);
    return temp[2];
}
```